# WPSE Plugin Repo

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, community-wiki

Yesterday I opened a new Q: [The WPSE Plugin Repository](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18459/wpse-plugin-repository-show-the-plugins-that-came-out-of-wa-answers).

After talking to @JanFabry & @Rarst in the chat, I want to ask you some Qs here.

---

**The ideas behind it are the following:**

**1.** Summon plugins created as Answers, so they don't get lost in the digital jungle

**2.** "Honor" the authors for their effort

**3.** Get a place that offers plugins that would hardly be found if they are not in the wp repo

**4.** Show what the community does over here (how much effort is invested into an Answer in comparison to other forum systems regarding wp)

**Questions:**

**1.** Please go and add your plugins :)

**2.** Upvote!

**3.** The "wpse-plugin" tag itself doesn't add anything meaningfull for the original Q. So should it stay there, or not? Please add a small pro/contra list, so we can sum them and then decide (I'll update the Q after new Answers or ask another one).

**4.** Should the WPSE-/WA-Plugin Repo be a a) Community Wiki b) Meta Question or c) a normal Question? Same as for the tag: Please offer some pro/contra.

---

As you might read between the lines: I'm *not* sure about this myself and therefore open for discussion with any possible end. So feel free to add anything you think about the idea, the tag or else.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 7):

I really like the idea of a central repository.

My suggestion:

Set up a WPSE GitHub Repository and whomever the community leaders that will eventually be in charge of the Blog would have commit access and they (along with help of the community) could find all the plugins and get them committed to the repo.  WPSE Plugins could be one of the blog categories that goes over a question and the answer that solved it with a custom plugin.

There could even be some empty Public Repositories that anyone could fork and add their code.  The admin could commit and rename it.

Comment: I really like the idea. But we will have to consider that there are currently only 3 moderators... the SE crew should be more generous to us to even have this possibility...

Comment: ...but if you would be so generous to care about the blank repository, I'd send you a link to my "blank" plugin as a starter. :)

Answer (score 4):

My issues with concept:

1. It's bad question. Essentially it is gathering trivia info about community.
2. It is destined to be collection of bad answers. Think about it - the strength of the format is either determining great definitive answer or collecting a lot of relevant information on topic (community wikis). Bunch of plugins, tied by meta criteria, are neither definitive of something or relevant to each other.

Does this mean I think it's bad idea? On the contrary - I think it's good idea, that has **no fitting place in format of the site**:

- on main site it sucks;
- on meta it will suck in obscure way;
- making it community wiki doesn't really save it.

I had passing idea that we might make tag wiki out of it, but that has editorial (rep to edit) and organizational (meta tags are evil) issues.

My suggestion would be to not try to hammer this into site. It would make much better content for community blog, we hope to get going - either as community news or maintained and prominent index of plugins.

Comment: it does seem sort of obvious that a wordpress community would have a blog, does it not? :)

Comment: Yes and that the blog was actually using WordPress.